# Select one instance of a text from list of XML elements with redundant text

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to create a list of filters to be applied to a list of news. I have the following piece of XML:

```
<filters>
   <filter>cars</filter>
   <filter>cars</filter>
   <filter>animals</filter>
   <filter>house</filter>
   <filter>sports</filter>
   <filter>cars</filter>
   <filter>house</filter>
</filters>
```

What I need to do, is to print out all of the different filters to the end user. So I want to run over the XML, but only print out a single filter once, so that the filter called "cars" won't be printet out three times but only once.
In fact the XML I want to end up with is the following:

```
<filters>
   <filter>cars</filter>
   <filter>animals</filter>
   <filter>house</filter>
   <filter>sports</filter>
</filters>
```

This would result in one instance of a filter in the XML.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

/Kim

Comment: The `distinct-values()` function is what you're probably looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="k" match="filter" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="filter[generate-id() != generate-id(key('k', .))]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think you can combine the two templates (i.e. `match="filter[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', .))]` and `match="filter"`) to one doing `<xsl:template match="filter[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', .)))]"/>`. That way the identity transformation template does the rest. And if the poster of the question is new to XSLT, then http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml can help understand it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I've used `!=` operator instead of `not` function.

Answer (score 1):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution.**

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFilterByVal" match="filter" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "filter[not(generate-id()
            =
             generate-id(key('kFilterByVal', .))
             )
         ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<filters>
    <filter>cars</filter>
    <filter>cars</filter>
    <filter>animals</filter>
    <filter>house</filter>
    <filter>sports</filter>
    <filter>cars</filter>
    <filter>house</filter>
</filters>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<filters>
   <filter>cars</filter>
   <filter>animals</filter>
   <filter>house</filter>
   <filter>sports</filter>
</filters>
```

**Explanation**: **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <filters>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by=".">
         <xsl:sequence select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </filters>   
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced.**

**Explanation**: Using the **[`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-for-each-group)** XSLT 2.0 instruction.